# html reference search box

Tags: javascript, html, search, input

I'm building a form from scratch in ServiceNow and want to have an input text field that is essentially a reference field to a table.  What I'm envisioning in my head is that it will be a text box that has a magnifying glass next to it where a user can click on it and it would query the necessary table.

For example, the field could be Employee Name and a user can click on the magnifying glass, which would open up the User table and they can choose which Employee Name they want.

My issue is I'm not even sure how to search for help on this.  Any help on how to get started would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If the user knows which employee name she or he is searching for, and depending on what browsers you need to support, this functionality could be accomplished using a `<datalist>`. It would be a little bit different than your vision, though.

Comment: So, you want to be able to click on something (a button, a link, just styled with a magnifying glass), and have a pop-up/modal show up where a user can select (and perhaps even limit the list) a name from a table of users (or whatever)? This isn't very hard to do - just have an ajax-call pull up the list when you click the icon, and code something that puts the selected name (clicked on, for instance) into the input-field.